# How can I handle multiple image uploads without the server slowing down?

Tags: python, django, server

I followed [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html) to upload multiple images with the help of AJAX.

To summarize it:

- I have a model that stores the images
- A form with an image field
- A view that handles the form in the post method
- AJAX sends a post request to this view

We have a server on Heroku, and the problem is if someone uploads a lot of images with a size greater than 5 MB per image the site is extremely slow, not only for the uploader, but for every other user as well.

How could we solve such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how much this will help, but I found some talk related to your question and I think you can use their approach. Please read the reddit post here : [File Uploads with Python](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5uyafm/handling_multigigabyte_file_uploads_with_python/)

I wanted to write this as a comment, since this doesn't immediately solve your problem, but I do not have the required rep to do so. Feel free to add it to comments.

Comment: Wow perfect, that's about the same scenario. That helps me a lot, thank you very much.